# How to configure the Styles in openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am very new to openlayers and trying to configure the styles for polygon, line and Point feature, once I configure the styles then I can able to call that styles whenever I define the layers. I tried this code but not working(tried only for polygon).

```
var test = {
  "polygon": {
    id: "polygon",
    style:  new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'green', width: 1})
    })
  },
  "polygon1": {
    id: "polygon1",                                     
    style:  new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'blue', width: 1})
    })
  }
};

var geojson_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'file.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  }),
  style: styleFunction
});
```

Comment: You're missing a chunk of code in your example.  If I may suggest, you should use your browser Dev Tool (F12) and put break points within your style function to see what's going on.  Try also removing your style from your layer to see if they render using the default styling.

Comment: My Question is I need to configure the styles based on attribute condition in one variable and need to call that styles for the features.

Comment: You could look at this example: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/translate-features.html, inside the `createTextStyle` function you'll see that feature properties are used to customize the style.

Comment: In that example he didn't used any openlayers styles api.

Comment: You're still missing a chunk in your example.  Would you please create a JSFiddle ?  Also, I don't understand that last statement.